# Infinite AJAX request on Safari (Mac)

Tags: jquery, safari

I need some help debugging JS that runs well on all Win browsers (including Safari), but not on the Mac version of Safari.

There's a log in screen on one of my sites that uses a jQuery modal window and an AJAX request. A complaint I received is that the log in request doesn't finish (ie. the "loading" image never disappears and the user doesn't get logged in) on Safari.

The request itself is a simple $.post that accepts a user's log in and essentially returns true or false.

The URL is http://i-marbella.com/ (log in is near the top right corner).

So the question I have is: can someone confirm this bug? And if so, are there any JS errors that could cause this?

Comment: Have you used any development tools to "watch" the ajax request while using Safari?

Comment: Yes, but as I said, the Windows version does not exhibit this behavior. My problem here is mainly that I have absolutely no way to access a Mac (there aren't even any Apple stores nearby).

Comment: Is this only on a Mac / Safari? Windows / Safari works OK?

Comment: Exactly. The Windows version works as expected, but I'm getting complaints from a Mac user.

Answer (score 0):

im assuming you're tying into the ajaxStart and ajaxStop methods either globally or per request. the only times i've ever had problems with the loading dialog not going away is when im returning some data to the page and something is wrong with it.

i get this a lot when im trying to append html from an ajax request to a div and the html i get back is either malformed or its referencing a css class not included on the page or even a js function not included. other times its happened, my json is not in the right format etc etc etc.

every single time this has happened to me, there have been errors in either the data im sending to the server or the data im getting back from the server.

Comment: Appreciate the answer. The data that's coming as a response to that request is plain text, contains no HTML or CSS and isn't actually inserted into the DOM (on a successful login). The callback function in turn does 2 $.get requests that return different parts of the user's UI as HTML. Neither of those pieces of HTML should be malformed in any way (they are also loaded statically once the user has logged in), but even if they were, the user should still be logged in, which would show up after a refresh.